# evenly align radio buttons vertically and horizontally in flexbox

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to both vertically and horizontally align Radio buttons in flexbox. This is what I did so far and the buttons are not aligned properly. Below is my code:

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
  <div class="navlist">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">XXXX</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">XXXXX</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
    <label for="other">XXXXX</label>

  </div>

  <div class="navlist">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">XXXXXXXX</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">YYYYYYYYYYYYY</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
    <label for="other">PPPPPPPPPPP</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do? 2 columns and 3 rows or 2 rows and 3 columns?

I assumed 2 columns and 3 rows. Then I changed  `flex-column` to `flex-row` and `justify-content-between` to `justify-content-around`. Then I got this, we can change the width of this container.

[image]

I haven't used any custom css. I hope this will help you

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
      <label for="male">XXXX</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
      <label for="female">XXXXX</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
      <label for="other">XXXXX</label>

    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
      <label for="male">XXXXXXXX</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
      <label for="female">YYYYYYYYYYYYY</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
      <label for="other">PPPPPPPPPPP</label>

    </div>
  </div>
```